# Installing plugin for wordpress website hosted locally is asking for ftp details

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I am working on locally hosted wordpress installation.

When I am on windows the wordpress installation is all fine.

But whenever I move to ubuntu then my plugin installation asks for host name, ftp username and password.

It happened several times for me earlier too. Previously I went through some thread and got a solution to use localhost as host name and use my operating system username and password for ftp details. Which worked for me then.

But now it is not working for me.

And sometimes changing the file permission worked too. But again in my current case it is not working.

So, instead of trying random results, I think it will be better if I know the root cause of why this is happening and then the correct solution to troubleshoot it.

So, if any one can help me here. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open wp-config.php file and add this code :

```
/** Setup FTP Details **/ 
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```